# Treat external javascript file as part of Aspx Page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I know you can't use asp net server tags in an external javascript file. This is a bit of pain, because it forces you to declare your variables that need ClientID in the aspx page and then you refer to them in the external javascript file. Not very clean. Currently I use script manager's composite script to register my scripts... It would be nice if I could have the script injected and the server tags processed as if it was part of the page. Is this possible?

I know there is RegisterClientScript but this doesn't seem to honor the script tags either. I'm wondering if there is a solution someone has come up with to just pull the contents of the javascript file and shove them into the aspx page before it's processed so that the server tags can be processed. I've looked all over the web and don't see any good solution to this beyond using the server tags in the aspx page or generating the ids of controls, etc. server side and generating script.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by RegisterClientScript not honoring the script tags? A little unsure of what the exact problem is. Perhaps an ideal page snippet showing what you are after might help?

Comment: The dynamic data should only be *in* the HTML (e.g ASP markup) only. Define an API to pass the data to the JavaScript file which is *kept external*. This leads to a more clear design as well as better cache utilization.

Comment: I do something like this: ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(upnlMain, upnlMain.GetType(), "Yoda", "MyScript.js"); Then in my script I have var ctrlid = '<%= upnlMain.ClientID  %>'... But this doesn't get processed as a server tag.

Comment: @KingOfHypocrites Yes, it *doesn't work like that* (only the aspx file processing works like that, and it's more complicated than a simple template). See my previous comment and how this should [likely] be coded. That is, this question is begging for answer X to problem Y when Z is [usually] the better solution.

Answer (score 2):

> I know you can't use asp net server tags in an external javascript
>   file

You can create an ASPX page to generate dynamic javascript

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false"
CodeFile="script.aspx.cs" Inherits="scripts_script"
EnableViewState="false" StyleSheetTheme="" %>
function test() {
    testinfo.innerHTML = "<%= MyVariable %>";
}
```

Make sure to set `StyleSheetTheme=""` otherwise the runtime will insert a `<head>` which you don't want

And in the code behind set the ContentType to `application/x-javascript`

```
using System;

public partial class scripts_script
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        this.Response.ContentType = "application/x-javascript";
    }
}
```

Now you can use this ASPX page as if it were a `.js` file.

Comment: This is pretty genius. The only downside is that it wouldn't have a .js extension. I'm also not sure how I would include the script into another page?

Comment: You can make it a .js file with some URL rewriting but that was beyond the scope of this question so I left it out, but you should be able to google that pretty easy. When you say `include the script into another page` do you mean as an external javascript file? If so just do it the same as you would any other external javasscript file.

Comment: So I'd have something like this? <Scripts> <asp:ScriptReference Path="ScoreCardsScript.aspx.cs" ScriptMode="Release" /> </Scripts> I'm not sure that would work. It would be nice if server side I could just point it to a JS file and it would process the server tags and give me the result.. Then I could register it as a script block.

Comment: I think so but don't include the `.cs`