# Visual Studio 2010: force syntax highlighting / intellisense for specific file

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, syntax-highlighting, intellisense

in a web application i've some dynamic **js** files, with **aspx** extension; i would to benefit the syntax highlighting / intellisense support for javascript while editing, but Visual Studio does not recognize the file as javascript.
Is there some way to force visual studio to threat a file with a custom "editing experience"?

Comment: I didn't catch, you mean a normal js file but with aspx extension, no header, no script tag?

Comment: yes; my js file look like <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#"  %>
<%
Response.ContentType = "application/x-javascript";
%>

.... js code ....

Comment: Did you have a look to this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782845/treat-external-javascript-file-as-part-of-aspx-page ?

Answer (score 0):

I am using a similar approach to what you are doing. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and I can fool it by adding a <script> tag in a code block that is not executed:

```
<%@ page language="C#" autoeventwireup="false" codefile="Script.aspx.cs" EnableViewState="false" inherits="Script" StyleSheetTheme="" %>

<% if (false){ %> <script type="text/javascript"> <% }%>

... Javascript goes here

<% if(false){ %> </script> <% }%>
```